# How to set multiple default values in a groupedlist type form field in joomla

Tags: joomla, form-fields

I'm creating my own template and I need to set multiple default values for a groupedlist type form field.

What i did:

```
<field name="grid-top" 
       type="groupedlist" 
       label="COM_TPL_MYTEMPLATE_DIV_TYPE_LABEL" 
       description="COM_TPL_MYTEMPLATE_DIV_TYPE_DESC"
       multiple="true" 
       class="big"
       default="VALUE-1, VALUE-2" />
```

however this way doesnt work. anyone please point me to a right direction, How can i set multiple default values ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML for your "groupedlist" form field? e.g. do mean a `select` with an `optgroup` or something else?

Comment: "groupedlist" is a standard joomla form-field to have list of options divided into groups. So, i havent used any custom HTML codes.

And YES it is a select with an optgroup.

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying been busy with work. I was just asking as you don't seem to know how to make a select list using JFields and I wanted to be sure before replying, anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value in the xml should be a JSON Encoded array.

So your XML should show as this:

```
<field name="grid-top" 
       type="groupedlist" 
       label="COM_TPL_MYTEMPLATE_DIV_TYPE_LABEL" 
       description="COM_TPL_MYTEMPLATE_DIV_TYPE_DESC"
       multiple="true" 
       class="big"
       default='["VALUE-1","VALUE-2"]' />
```

Also note that values must be protected by a double quote so you need to use a single quote to encalsulate the whole default value.
Using default="['VALUE-1','VALUE-2']" would not work.

Comment: This is the right answer to this question thanks Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

To use the `GroupedList` you build it as you would a standard `list` you just wrap the options for each `group` in it's own `<group />` element. You can also mix `group`'s and stand-alone `option`s in the same `list` menu.

e.g this example shows groups and options, you can of course use `JText` keys rather than straight text as I used in the example.

```
   <field name="experimentalGroupedList"
           type="groupedlist"
           label="Grouped List Experiment"
           default="0" >
        <option value="">Standard Option</option>
        <group label="Group #1">
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
        </group>
        <group label="Group #2 — Amphibians">
            <option value="frog">Frog</option>
            <option value="caecilian">Caecilian</option>
            <option value="salamander">Salamander</option>
        </group>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </field>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what i really want is: I want to set "0" from "group #1" and "frog" from "group #2 -Amphibians" as default values. I want to set multiple default values and sorry that my question was not so clear.

Comment: A `<select>` element can only have **one** selected option (i.e. default) — http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html.

Answer (score 0):

Field type **list** doesn't provide any option to set two or more default values.
You can do it by using the singular model.

Find the singular model and find the function like `public function getItem($pk = null)` (if not exists then create it)

The function would be looked like this -

```
public function getItem($pk = null) {
    if ($item = parent::getItem($pk)) {
        if (empty($item->experimentalGroupedList)) {
            $item->experimentalGroupedList = array('VALUE-1', 'VALUE-2');
        }
        return $item;
    }
    return parent::getItem($pk);
}
```

This will set the default values for a multiple list field when no saved value found. 
Hope this will solve your problem.